# CNN resize images

Tags: machine-learning, cnn, image-classification

Reducing images size will cause a loss of information for sure.
If a have a model that perform better on resized images (50x50) than on original size images (224x224), what can I deduce ?

There is a lot of noise in the images data, the model is not enough complex to learn from all the data or something else ?

Comment: Are these models trained on the same data but resized? Same architecture, same everything? It could be to a lot of reasons, even randomness (if you don't have enough training samples). ONE possible reason: 224x224 images can create filters that tend to pay attention on background data instead of the main thing, 50x50 image can pay attention only to the foreground image.

Comment: Yes on same data, architecture and everything. It's a strange behaviour anyway your observation makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Using bigger image does not mean better results. It increases computaional cost. As stated in comment section, it might be creating filters that focus on the background of the image. Also, if dataset is noisy you need to apply some filter, for instance Gaussian noise.